# How to use single video camera for different .exe files

Tags: opencv

I have two binary files containing opencv programs both taking frames from single video camera. But on running both simultaneously gives only one program running whereas other program shows blank window. How to solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: typically camera are "blocked" by one process. Could you use the same camera at the same time for skype and vlc (or 2 different applications)?

Comment: you can `close` / `release` the camera after capturing an image, so that the other process is allowed to use it. Depends on your application, whether this is feasible

Comment: or you create a third process which is the only one that accesses the camera and the other processes ask that third one to capture and deliver the images.